# what is meant by behavior (Implementation code) exchange in OOP

Tags: web-services, oop, design-patterns

I am reading a book on BPEL and Webservices.I Read the following statement that i am  unable to understand.

```
Services exchange only data, which differs considerably from object oriented
and component approaches, where behavior (implementation code) can
also be exchanged.
```

Now what does it means?? Can anyone come with an example??

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of an object-oriented class is data and behaviour. The data are the class's fields/properties/attributes and its behaviour is its methods. Take away the behaviour and your left with just data, or what might be called a Data Transfer Object (DTO).

When you pass data to a web service you can only pass the data part. The methods that make up the class's behaviour are not passed as well. This is because services tend to be language independent.

On the other hand, within a given language, references to classes can be passed around freely. In this situation, the class's data and its behaviour are 'exchanged'.